# MySQL connection problem with internal IP

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have two servers and from one server I want to connect MySQL using internal IP. I am using mysql 5.7.25

I did following things:

```
 INSERT INTO mysql.user (User,Host,authentication_string,ssl_cipher,x509_issuer,x509_subject)VALUES('username','ip',PASSWORD('password'),'','','');
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'ip';
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'%';
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'loalhost';
```

In `etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` I commented following line:

```
 #bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

But its still not allowing to connect using IP.

Can anyone please suggest?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post the error message?

Comment: last row write localhost instead of loalhost ' GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'**loalhost**';'

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the following conditions are met:

1. Make sure there is no other un-commented `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` in other configuration file like `/etc/my.cnf` or any other .cnf file below `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/`. In case you find any, just comment it too.
2. Restart the mysql service to apply the changes. Run either one of the commands below depending on the Linux version you use.

   `systemctl restart mysqld`

   `service mysql restart`
3. Make sure there is no firewall on the server blocking port 3306 or whatever other port is mysql service listening on.
4. Make sure that on the client machine you correctly specify the IP of the server machine where the client is supposed to connect:

   `mysql -h server_ip -u username -p`